# How to set transition effect in carousal (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am trying to add a nice transition effect in my React app using material UI. I prepared this carousel in which I am having a hard time giving a smooth slide effect for user experience.

```
<div>
  {this.state.images.length !== 0 &&
  <div>
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', margin: 5}}>
      <img src={`${this.state.host}${this.state.path}${this.state.images[this.state.currentImage]}`}  alt='nope' style={{ width: '100%', height: '300px', position: 'absolute' }} />
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between', width: '100%', height: '300px',alignItems:'center' }}>
        <IconButton onClick={this.prevSlide.bind(this)}><ChevronLeft color="inherit"/></IconButton>
        <IconButton onClick={this.nextSlide.bind(this)}><ChevronRight color="inherit" /></IconButton>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>}
</div>
```

Comment: it will be helpful if you made a fiddle or sandbox sample

Comment: its actually a component in component. I am trying to place `style={{transition: all 0.8s}}` but its not working anywhere. BTW this is whole part of that particular component